# Is there any particularity of Sum/Product in replacement

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, summation

Here is an simple replacement:

```
 Log[x[k]] /. Log[a_] -> a*xbar
```

I get the answer in my mind:

```
xbar x[k]
```

Similarly, I use another replacement:

```
Sum[x[k],{k,1,n}]/.Sum[a_,{k,1,n}]->a*xbar
```

Should the answer be  `x[k]*xbar` ? However, the replacement is disappointing:

[image]

I remain puzzled after much pondering. It seems the function Product at it also is deceptive.

What is the particularity of Sum/Product in replacement? Why is that?

Comment: What do you expect after applying the rule? `Sum[x[k] xbar,{k,1,n}]`?

Answer (score 4):

If a function doesn't own `Hold*` attribute, it'll evaluate its arguments from left to right. `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) and `Rule` (`/.`) don't own `Hold*` attribute. In other words, `Sum[a_, {k, 1, n}]` evaluates before the replacement happens. There's no explicit `k` in `a_`, so `Sum` *thinks* it's a constant and evaluates to `n a_`. This can be checked with `Trace`:

```
Sum[x[k], {k, 1, n}] /. Sum[a_, {k, 1, n}] -> a xbar // Trace
```

[image]

Then how to fix? Just stop summing with `HoldPattern`:

```
Sum[x[k], {k, 1, n}] /. HoldPattern@Sum[a_, {k, 1, n}] -> a xbar
```

Alternatively:

```
Sum[x[k], {k, 1, n}] /. (h : Sum)[a_, {k, 1, n}] -> a xbar
```

Or:

```
Sum[x[k], {k, 1, n}] /. Verbatim[Sum][a_, {k, 1, n}] -> a xbar
```

Comment: Or make the index a pattern: `Sum[x[k], {k, 1, n}] /. Sum[a_, {k_, 1, n}] :> a*xbar`

Comment: @bob Interesting, I didn't know summing will stop evaluation in this case. (Even `Sum[a_, {h : k, 1, n}]` evaluates to `n a_`! )

Comment: I am only guessing but I suspect that in the process of localizing the index variable, internally `k` doesn't look like `k`. Using a pattern would cause a match to whatever its representation.

Comment: Thanks. I've learned Attrbute of Hold*,  useful Trace.

Comment: @BobHanlon  I wonder how you find it, accidentally.

Comment: @xzczd     These techniques seems advanced to a layman like me. Is there any excellent book detailed for in-depth study? MMA is so powerful.

Comment: @jerry - As I indicated, I guessed that localization might change the representation, and generalized the form of the LHS of the rule to see if that helped.

Comment: @BobHanlon Cool!

Comment: @jerry - Make use of the online documentation. Wolfram's [`book`](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) is online.

Comment: @BobHanlon  Ok. Thanks!

Comment: @jerry Also, don't miss Leonid Shifrin's book: http://mathprogramming-intro.org/ You can find more resource here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/1871